# Using multiple satellite constellations (e.g. GLONASS, GALILEO) by GPS unit?

Tags: gps

I am trying to do research on GNSS/GPS units available and it seems like there is a large price jump for units with more satellite constellations (maybe I am erroneously making this correlation) that the unit is connecting to.

Specifically, I was trying to compare the arrow lite and arrow 100 (and other brands) and it seems like the only major difference but there is a price difference of 1k between the two.

What is the advantage of having multiple constellations?

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of having multiple constellations is that the unit has a "view" of more satellites in the sky without having to use differential corrections. This helps with accuracy in general, in urban canyons, under canopies, and in poor weather. So, it depends on the field accuracy you need, and/or if you have access to post-processing capabilities.

Here is an article have nicely expands on what I have touched on. It is slightly outdated, as more satellites have been brought online, but the underlying principles are still relevant.

http://www.nature.com/articles/srep08328

Comment: So potentially if I am not operating in a big city, jungle or canyon (say mostly small communities), I might be able to get away with less constellations? Thanks for the info.

Comment: I added a link to a more detailed explanation of the capabilities of multi-GNSS. Hopefully, this will answer any questions you have.

Comment: Thank you, it's hard to find good information on the subject since it seems like something written even a couple years ago on GNSS is already outdated info. I appreciate your time.